# Twilio Programmable Wireless - Message Blocking is active

Tags: twilio

I am working with the NB Alpha Kit from Signal 2018.  The SIM is connected to the T-Mobile network (blue LED on):

```
  AT+COPS?  
  +COPS: 0,0,"T-Mobile",9
  OK
```

When I try to send a command from the SIM I get:

```
  AT+CMGS="2936"
  > HELLO
  +CMGS: 7
  OK
```

When I try to send from the API, the Command stays in a queued status and when I try to recieve it with the SIM, I get:

```
  AT+CMGL
  +CMGL: 0,"REC UNREAD","2936",,"19/09/10,00:14:10-20"
   Free Msg: Unable to send message - Message Blocking is active.
  OK
```

Any ideas on how to get messages flowing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The NB-IoT network is not intended for communications use and thus doesn't support SMS at this time. The message you sent from the SIM likely didn't go anywhere either.

However, we recognise that you should receive an error message when trying to send messages to a SIM that doesn't support it. We will look into making that an error in the API rather than queueing and never sending the message.